# technical requirement to running a Bitcoin node

Tags: nodes, full-node

I want to run a full node in order to support the network, however i am wondering about what are the technical requirements to do so.

how much RAM(for utxo) do I need? and what internet throughput will be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node) suggests the following minimum system requirements:

> - Desktop or laptop hardware running recent versions of Windows, Mac OS X, or Linux.
> - 145 gigabytes of free disk space
> - 2 gigabytes of memory (RAM)
> - A broadband Internet connection with upload speeds of at least 400 kilobits (50 kilobytes) per second
> - An unmetered connection, a connection with high upload limits, or a connection you regularly monitor to ensure it doesn’t exceed its upload limits. It’s common for full nodes on high-speed connections to use 200 gigabytes upload or more a month. Download usage is around 20 gigabytes a month, plus around an additional 140 gigabytes the first time you start your node.
> - 6 hours a day that your full node can be left running. (You can do other things with your computer while running a full node.) More hours would be better, and best of all would be if you can run your node continuously.

Comment: As of 2019 this answer is no longer up to date. At least not with respect to disk space. Today you need at least 250 GB.

Comment: @Thorkil feel free to update the answer, although the website suggests 200 GB not 250 GB